# F12 to access Ubuntu dual boot alongside Windows 8.1?

Tags: ubuntu, multi-boot

I installed Ubuntu alongside Windows 8.1 in UEFI mode. The problem is that I only can access the Ubuntu by pressing the F12 key(image below), which forces the boot.

[image: Dual boot problem]

On another computer with dual boot I did not have this problem, perhaps because they had no UEFI mode.

This is normal? Is there any way to have dual boot without repeatedly pressing the F12 key?

Comment: What exactly are you asking is normal?  You need to replace the Windows bootloader with Grub if you want to avoid this behavior.

Comment: Try using Bootrepair,  https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Problem solved as follows:**

1. Follow the second option: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair
2. Boot-Repair will ask to run a command prompt in Windows at the end of the process, which in my case was:

> bcdedit /set {bootmgr} path \EFI\ubuntu\shimx64.efi

**Note:** You will need to start the Windows prompt as administrator. Press *Windows + X* then *"Run as Administrator"*.

Answer (score 2):

For some reason when you installed Ubuntu grub didn't install right. You will want grub since it will easily let you select Ubuntu or windows. [Here's a guide on how to install grub.](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Grub2/Installing)

Comment: The boot-repair started from the live CD has the same effect? I not tested yet because I'm afraid of damaging my Windows installation and at the moment there 's no way I perform a backup.

Comment: It should but I'm not positive. Definitely make a backup first though since it seems you can run windows fine. The repair shouldn't mess with Windows though... in theory.